# Change the form of the artboard (Illustrator or Indesign) and save it as PDF without background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, png, background-removal

I want to create a PDF for a customer in which each page has a different shape than a quadrangle. It should be a PDF-file without a background (also no grid or no white background). In the end each site should look like a PNG file but it has to be a multiple paged PDF.

I tried a view things but nothing really worked. I thought it could be the best way to create each site as a PNG and create a PDF afterwards. But I can not find a way to get rid of the whole background in Adobe Acrobat. That means I also do not want to see the transparency grid or the white back ground. I want to have the "empty" parts the colour of the actual background like it is with an PNG file.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is this actually going to be used for? What is your ultimate goal? Why are you trying to do this? None of these things are possible in a PDF. You can't have non-rectangular pages. You can have transparency in a PDF, but the default page in Acrobat is always white, unless the viewer switches on the transparency grid, which you say you don't want.  At the moment, your question reads like [an X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You also mention "each site" what are you referring to? Do you want flip pages for a website?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done. At least not with most PDF readers.

PDFs don't *really* have a background, you *can* turn on the transparency grid in Acrobat similar to other Adobe apps. The white is traditional for printing, since nothing white ever actually prints. PDFs are designed to be printable documents, thus the white background.

I'd also point out that **all** images are rectangles. All of them.

This really seems like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) overall.